# How do you parse text in Ruby on Rails and add classes to specific parts of it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a Rails novice and I'm creating an application that I'd love some help on. The app is for social reading. It enables a user to highlight a passage from a text then have that passage saved and bolded into the view for later reading by anyone else.

I have no problem creating an if statement on whether a certain string of text is in a passage but how do I add a class to that string and have a group of these passages absorbed back into the view. Any strategic advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think this a case where additional modeling of the domain would be useful. A string of text is simply too generic to encapsulate all of the data about itself. For example, in this case, you are struggling to store information about **specific parts of the string** in the string itself.

Instead, I suggest the following modeling of the problem domain:

Note: I am assuming that you already have a model called `Article` which currently has a field/property called `text`.

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :passage
end
```

and

```
class Passage < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article
    has_many :highlighted sections

    # sample database fields
    # text -- the entire text
end
```

and

```
class HighlightedSection < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :passage

    # sample database fields
    # int start -- the (string) index of the start of the passage
    # int end -- the (string) index of the end of the passage
end
```

Together, this model allows you to store sections. You could also expand the model to ensure that passages do not overlap, etc.

Good luck with your application!